# Email field with unique constraint prevents PUT method of serializer from saving. django rest_framework

Tags: django, api

When creating an object in my api view it seems fine but whenever I update the object even I didn't change my email field it says `user with this Email Address already exists.` I am using `generics.RetrieveUpdateView` for my view.

I thought `generics.RetrieveUpdateView` automatically handles this. What am I missing?

my model looks like this:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    email= models.EmailField(unique=True)

    ...
```

my serializer looks like this:

```
class UserListForProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', 'username','email','last_login', 'date_joined','is_active', 'is_student', 'is_staff', 'is_teacher', 'is_registrar', 'is_superuser']
        read_only_fields = ('username','date_joined', 'last_login','is_active', 'is_student', 'is_staff', 'is_teacher', 'is_registrar', 'is_superuser')



class StaffProfileDetailSerializer(CreateProfileSerializer):
    user = UserListForProfileSerializer(many= False)
    class Meta:
        model = StaffProfile
        fields = ['user','first_name', 'middle_name', 'last_name', 'gender', 'employee_number', 'date_of_birth', 'mobile_number','dob_month','dob_day','dob_year','address',]
        read_only_fields = ('date_joined', 'last_login',)
```

my view looks like this:

```
class UserProfileDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    authentication_classes = [SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    serializer_class = StaffProfileDetailSerializer

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        userid = self.request.user.id
        return StaffProfile.objects.filter(pk= userid)
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('api/', apiOverview, name='apioverview'),
    path('api/user/profile/detail/<int:pk>/', UserProfileDetail.as_view(), 
           name='userprofile-detail'),

    ...

]
```

Comment: Show your url pattern for the view `UserProfileDetail`.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I updated my question for you to see the urls.py